# poisson and uniform distributions

Tags: probability, stochastic-processes, uniform-distribution, poisson-distribution, poisson-process

I have an answer to this question from someone else but I do not think it is right. Here is the question:

Customers arrive at a bank at a Poisson rate lambda. Suppose two customers arrive during the first hour. What is the probability that both arrived during the first 20 minutes?

The answer I have says the arrivals are uniform (0,60). How can that be?

Comment: A Poisson process is memoryless.  Would you expect a particular individual arrival to be more likely to be in the initial third, the middle third or the final third of the hour?  Would the you expect the arrival of two particular individuals to be dependent on or independent of each other?

Comment: All equally likely. Independent. Got it. Thanks

Comment: What do you mean by "arrivals", it seems that you are referring to a single random variable, but at the same time you are using plural...you mean the arrival time of each customer, individually? By other hand, if we are told that the customers arrive at a Poisson rate, shouldn't be the time between the arrivals modeled as exponential?...

Answer (score 1):

2 ways to obtain the same answer (1/9), 1 easier than the other. Both use the [definition of conditional probability](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conditional_probability#Definition) as the quotient of joint probability and probability of 1 RV, but the easier method considers number of customers as RVs, while the other considers arrival times.

1. Let $n(t)$ be an RV for the number of customers arriving during time $t$. Since $n(t)$ increments in disjoint intervals are Poisson and thus independent, the probability of $n(t_1)$ given $n(t_2)$ is

$$
\frac{P(n(t_1)\cap n(t_2))}{P_{Poi}(n(t_2);\lambda t_2)}=\frac{P_{Poi}(n(t_1);\lambda t_1)P_{Poi}(n(t_2)-n(t_1);\lambda(t_2-t_1))}{P_{Poi}(n(t_2);\lambda t_2)}
$$

2. Let $\tau_i$ be an RV for the arrival time of customer i. Then $\Delta \tau_i$ are [independent and exponentially distributed](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Poisson_point_process#Counting_process_interpretation). The desired probability is the probability $\tau_i<t_1$ given $\tau_i<t_2$ and $\tau_{i+1}>t_2$, or

$$
\frac{P_t(\tau_i<t_1\cap\tau_i<t_2\cap\tau_{i+1}>t_2)}{P_t(\tau_i<t_2\cap\tau_{i+1}>t_2)}=\frac{P_t(\tau_i<t_1\cap\tau_{i+1}>t_2)}{P_t(\tau_i<t_2\cap\tau_{i+1}>t_2)}
$$
$$
P_t(\tau_i<t\cap\tau_{i+1}>t_2)=\int_0^td\Delta\tau_1...\int_0^{t-\sum_{j=1}^{i-1}\Delta\tau_j}d\Delta\tau_i\int_{t_2-\sum_{j=1}^i\Delta\tau_j}^\infty d\Delta\tau_{i+1}\prod_{j=1}^{i+1}P_{exp}(\Delta\tau_j;\lambda)
$$